# gluLookAt trouble

Tags: opengl, lwjgl, glu

I have some code which draws a line along the x, y and z axes. My problem is that these lines are being clipped so that they are invisible near the origin:

[image: clipped axes]

This sounds like a far clipping plane issue, but I gave zFar=50 to gluPerspective, which should be plenty. Making it even larger doesn't seem to help. What else could be causing the clipping?

Here is my code:

```
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;
import org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU;

public class Test {
    static int width = 300, height = 200;

    public static void main(String[] _) throws Exception {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(width, height));
        Display.create();
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // projection matrix
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX);
        glLoadIdentity();
        GLU.gluPerspective(50, width / (float) height, .1f, 50);

        // modelview matrix
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        GLU.gluLookAt(
                .8f, .8f, .8f,
                0, 0, 0,
                0, 1, 0);

        // draw a line for each axis
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
            // x axis in red
            glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
            glVertex3i(0, 0, 0);
            glVertex3i(10, 0, 0);
            // y axis in green
            glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
            glVertex3i(0, 0, 0);
            glVertex3i(0, 10, 0);
            // z axis in blue
            glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
            glVertex3i(0, 0, 0);
            glVertex3i(0, 0, 10);
        glEnd();

        Display.update();

        // wait for a close event
        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            Thread.sleep(20);
            Display.processMessages();
        }
        Display.destroy();
    }
}
```

**Update** - Removing `glLoadIdentity();` after `glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);` gives the desired result, but I don't understand why. Isn't the default modelview matrix the identity matrix?

**Update** - I wrote a C version of the same code and it works as desired. Why the difference?

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: I put one at the top, does it not show up for you?

Comment: Maybe you should draw your objects every frame instead of drawing them once and then repeatedly calling swapBuffers with `update()`. You should put everything between `// modelview matrix` and `glEnd()` at the beginning of the while-loop that follows. Also put a call to `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)` at the very start of the loop for good measurement

Comment: Fair points - I shouldn't be swapping buffers after not drawing anything, and I shouldn't assume that the color buffer will be zero-initialized. But these changes don't fix the problem I'm having.

Comment: shouldn't that be `glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);` instead of `glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, after testing it, it turns out that `glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX);` should be `glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);` instead.

So it seems that the modelview was active by default and `glLoadIdentity()` cleared the results of `GLU.gluPerspective(50, width / (float) height, .1f, 50);`

edit: Btw. in case you wonder what `GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX` is for, it's to retrieve the current matrix from the top of the matrix stack with `glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX,output);` or `glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX,output);`

Comment: Ah, good catch! Thanks, I'll give you the bounty as soon as SO lets me.